# Get url not working in Kannel

Tags: kannel

I have configured kannel & i receive sms at bearerbox but URL containing the required action to be taken using receivesms php script is not called. receivesms script in php works fine when i call it externally, but kannel does not invokes the get-url as mentioned in the "SMS service" box & below access logs is repeating again and again in the logs & also smsbox logs doesn't have any logs related to this transaction. Please suggest what can be wrong in the configurationKannel configuration is as follows

```
group = core
admin-port = 13010
smsbox-port = 13012
admin-allow-ip = "10.130.252.160,127.0.0.1"
log-file = "/u03/kannel/logs/bearerbox.log"
box-allow-ip = "10.130.252.160,127.0.0.1"
access-log = "/u03/kannel/logs/bearerbox_access.log"
dlr-storage = internal

##############################TX-1################################## 
group = smsc
smsc-id ="MT"
smsc = smpp
host =10.10.22.10
port = 5016
smsc-username = "CC_APPS"
smsc-password = "apps"
system-type = "INAPPS"
interface-version = 34
receive-port =0
source-addr-ton = 1
source-addr-npi = 1  
dest-addr-ton = 1
dest-addr-npi = 1
keepalive = 30
log-level =0
throughput = 50
max-pending-submits=50
reconnect-delay = 60
reroute = true
log-file = "/u03/kannel/logs/smsc_conn.log"


######################RX-1################################
group = smsc
smsc-id ="MTS"
smsc = smpp
host =10.10.22.10
port = 0
smsc-username = "CC_APPS"
smsc-password = "apps"
system-type = "INAPPS"
receive-port =5016
interface-version = 34
source-addr-ton = 1
source-addr-npi = 1
dest-addr-ton = 1
dest-addr-npi = 1
keepalive = 30
log-level =0
reconnect-delay = 60
reroute = true
log-file = "/u03/kannel/logs/smsc_conn.log"

group = smsbox
bearerbox-host = 127.0.0.1
sendsms-port = 13013
global-sender = YD-MTS
log-file = "/u03/kannel/logs/smsbox.log"
log-level = 0

#SMSBOX ROUTING
group = smsbox-route
smsbox-id = smsbox
smsc-id ="MT"

group = sendsms-user
username = smsg
password = smsg@123
default-smsc="MT"
concatenation= true
max-messages = 6


group = sms-service
keyword = default
url = http://10.130.250.58/receivesms.php?sender=%p&text=%b
catch-all = true
max-messages = 1
text = "This is a reply"
```

bearerbox access log is as follows

```
 2015-11-12 09:04:53 Sent SMS [SMSC:MTS] [SVC:] [ACT:MTSCC_APPS] [BINF:]   [FID:AFB4EE11] [META:?smpp??smpp_resp?] [from:+919136006473] [to:+9177775] [flags:-1:0:-1:0:-1] [msg:2:Hi] [udh:0:]
 2015-11-12 09:04:53 Receive SMS [SMSC:MTS] [SVC:] [ACT:MTSCC_APPS] [BINF:] [FID:] [META:?smpp?] [from:+919136006473] [to:+9177775] [flags:-1:0:-1:0:-1] [msg:2:Hi] [udh:0:]
 2015-11-12 09:04:53 Receive SMS [SMSC:MTS] [SVC:] [ACT:MTSCC_APPS] [BINF:] [FID:] [META:?smpp?] [from:+919136006473] [to:+9177775] [flags:-1:0:-1:0:-1] [msg:2:Hi] [udh:0:]
 2015-11-12 09:04:53 Sent SMS [SMSC:MTS] [SVC:] [ACT:MTSCC_APPS] [BINF:] [FID:AFB4EE31] [META:?smpp??smpp_resp?] [from:+919136006473] [to:+9177775] [flags:-1:0:-1:0:-1] [msg:2:Hi] [udh:0:]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this sms-service instead. You are missing "get-" before url I think.

```
group = sms-service
keyword = default
get-url = http://10.130.250.58/receivesms.php?sender=%p&text=%b
catch-all = true
max-messages = 0
accept-x-kannel-headers = true
assume-plain-text = true
```